# node.js + 7zip + exec(Sync) no archive created?

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line-interface, 7zip

I've got the following js code which is supposed to add all the files in the current directory to a 7z archive:

```
"use strict";
const { execSync } = require("child_process");
process.chdir("C:\\Program Files\\7-Zip\\");

let clicommand = "7z a Files.7z " + __dirname + "\\ *.* -r";

execSync(clicommand, (error) => {
  if (error) {
    console.log(`error: ${error.message}`);
    return;
  }
});

console.log("Current dir: " + __dirname);
console.log("clicommand : " + clicommand);
```

If launch it from the terminal window in VS Code.
It's doing something for a a second or so, then prints out:

```
Current dir: D:\node\node_http_server
clicommand : 7z a Files.7z D:\node\node_http_server\ *.* -r
```

But there is no zip archive being created in D:\node\node_http_server.
Runing the command

```
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a Files.7z *.* -r
```

directly from the console works fine, where is my mistake?

Comment: `execSync` does not take a callback -- it returns the stdout of the command https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execsync_command_options. Also, the second command is missing the `"D:\node\node_http_server"`. What happens if you run the exact same command in the shell? And what are the contents of the return value of execSync?

Comment: I've also tried exec(), same result.
Which second command?
Runing in shell it creates the archive.

Comment: I've just checked C:\Program Files\7-Zip\ dir, the archive is there, hmm